# Labeling object in a binary image MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary, label, bounding-box

I am trying to label white objects in a binary image using MATLAB. Basically, my aim is to detect water bodies in a aerial map image and then convert the cimage to binary and then label the bodies. Here is an image example of my output after detecting the bodies and converting to binary. How can I now possibly create a create rectangle around the white objects and label them with text(using connected components)? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Do you have the Image Processing Toolbox? If so, look into `regionprops` that can return the bounding boxes

Comment: Yeas I have the image processing toolbox. I was looking into that, just could not figure out how to use it.

Comment: I think I figured it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
%%// Read in the image file
img = im2bw(imread(FILE));

%%// Get bounding box stats
stats = regionprops(bwlabel(img),'Area','Centroid','Perimeter','BoundingBox');
Boxes=cat(1,stats.BoundingBox);

%%// Placeholder to store the final result
maskm = false(size(img,1),size(img,2));

for k1 = 1:size(Boxes,1)

    %%// Initialize a mask representing each bounding box
    mask1 = false(size(img,1),size(img,2));

    %%// Get the coordinates of the boxes
    starty = round(Boxes(k1,1));
    stopy = starty+round(Boxes(k1,3))-1;
    startx = round(Boxes(k1,2));
    stopx = startx+round(Boxes(k1,4))-1;

    %%// Finaly create the mask
    mask1(startx:stopx,starty:stopy) = true;
    maskm = maskm + imdilate(edge(mask1,'sobel'),strel('disk',2));
end

%%// Get the boxes around the original blobs
maskm = maskm + img;
figure,imshow(maskm);
```

**Output**

[image]

Look into [text](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/text.html) on how to label the boxes.

Comment: Dude, that is excellent! Thanks a lot! Now, is it possible to add text on top of the box?

Comment: Oh sorry, just saw that last line where you have linked to a solution for how to add text! Thank you again!

Comment: For labeling, you may use another loop and put something like this - `text(startx,starty,'Box1')` after you have `startx` and `starty`. It's just an example.